# Получение ссылки из текста

Tags: html, c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть такой текст:

```
<div id="photos_container" class="clear_fix">
    <div class="photo_row" id="photo_row-64876876_373778105">
        <a href="/photo-64876876_373778105" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" ontouchmove="cancelEvent(event);" onclick="if (cur.cancelClick) return (cur.cancelClick = false); return showPhoto('-64876876_373778105', 'album-64876876_218966376', {img: this, root: 1}, event)">
            <img class="photo_row_img" src="https://pp.vk.me/c623716/v623716891/3cc56/mhoiHY11osU.jpg" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="photo_row" id="photo_row-64876876_373778113">
            <a href="/photo-64876876_373778113" ontouchstart="event.cancelBubble = true;" ontouchmove="cancelEvent(event);" onclick="if (cur.cancelClick) return (cur.cancelClick = false); return showPhoto('-64876876_373778113', 'album-64876876_218966376', {img: this, root: 1}, event)">
```

Как из него получить `https://pp.vk.me/c623716/v623716891/...hoiHY11osU.jpg`?

Answer (score 3):

Тут все зависит от того, насколько эта конструкция устойчиво повторяется на странице. Если цель -- использовать регулярные выражения, то можно попробовать что-то такое:

```
/img\s+class=\"photo_row_img\"\s+src=\"([^\"]+)\"/i
```

А еще, для таких задач можно использовать готовые HTML парсеры. Возможно, это окажется удобнее и надежнее.

Answer (score 3):

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(original_text, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```